# Getting null value when I trying to read 'name' value from 'AbstractPromotionModel'?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

```
public void populate(final AbstractPromotionModel source, final PromotionData target)
{
    final String name = source.getName();
    target.setName(name);
    ...
}
```

In above source code I am getting `null` value, however the value is found in database.

Comment: Do you have any stacktraces? A bit more information on what the issue is would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a localized value? If so, than you need to get the value with the localizationService.